# any type of join not returning null in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

None of the join type in Codeigniter returns null value in case of matching left and right table. This is my controller function which prints only three records
[here price table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AQ5R.png)

```
    function product_offers(){

        $this->db->select('p1.id as product_id, p1.UID as product_uid, p1.name as product_name, p2.price as offer_price, p3.price as selling_price');

        $this->db->from('product as p1');
        $this->db->join('price as p2', 'p2.table_id = p1.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('price as p3', 'p3.table_id = p1.id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('p2.tag', 'offer_price');
        $this->db->where('p3.tag', 'selling_price');
        $this->db->where('p2.table_name', 'product');
        $this->db->where('p3.table_name', 'product');


        $q = $this->db->get();

        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            $pagedata['product_prices'] =  $q->result_array(); 
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($pagedata);
            echo '</pre>';
        }   

    }
```

Comment: I tried left, right, inner, left outer instead of third parameter of join but nothing been changed in output

Comment: And if you remove those 'where' clauses?

Comment: i need to include where condition

Comment: But at least you now know what's wrong with your query

Comment: You need to make first raw query and check it out with IDE (`MySQLWorkbench`)